# better solution to gui code?

Tags: c#, radio-button, panel, checkbox

Just learning  C#, radiobuttons and checkboxes. No urgency. 
The code works to display the names of the checked controls but it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TVC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "you clicked" + compute();
        }


        string compute()
        {
            string result = "";
            object o=label1;

            while (((Control)o).TabIndex!=7)
            {
                if ((o is RadioButton)||(o is CheckBox))
                {

                    if ((o is RadioButton)&&((RadioButton)o).Checked)

                    result += " "+((RadioButton)o).Text;

                    if ((o is CheckBox)&&((CheckBox)o).Checked)

                    result += " "+((CheckBox)o).Text;

                }

                o = GetNextControl((Control)o, true);
            }



            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The checboxes and radiobuttons tabindexes are counted from 1to 6, the label is 0 and the button is 7 so that GetNextControl works.  Is there a nicer code that would work ?[image]

Comment: Whatever you do, always avoid magic numbers. Even if this is the final code you go with, extract that `7` to a separate constant.

Comment: +1 For a good suggestion on Magic numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and verified that it works. It uses recursion and the newer `dynamic` keyword as it appears that `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` inherit from `ButtonBase`, which does not have the `Checked` property, otherwise you could cast down to that. The dynamic allows me to avoid that since I already know the control types.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = compute(this.Controls);
    }
    private string compute(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control.Controls != null)
                result += compute(control.Controls);
            if (control is RadioButton || control is CheckBox)
            {
                dynamic checkControl = control;
                if (checkControl.Checked)
                {
                    result += checkControl.Text + ";";
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself using the `is` and `as` keyword to control branching, there's a great chance that you're not leveraging [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

If you want to have controls that can display their own state based on the logic in your program, one cleaner approach would be to subclass each control and override `ToString()`.

Place the logic for creating a text representation in the control, not in code that uses a number of controls (how complex will your branching logic get if you add 10 new control types?)

Finally, I would use a `foreach` rather than a `while` with a hard-coded number to iterate through the controls.